# How large can a fermi level get?

Tags: electronic-band-theory, fermi-energy

Long text. I wish to be corrected where I'm wrong, it's all about Fermi levels. The last thing I'm trying to figure out is what absolute Fermi level means to circuits.

The difference in Fermi levels between two metal bodies makes a battery. It's the Fermi difference that gives the voltage: V=(F1-F2)/e or something like that (doesn't matter). So voltage is relative in this model, it's about relative Fermi levels.

The absolute Fermi levels cannot be ignored, because anything you connect to this battery has its own Fermi level. You will get an ESD if there is a large difference between the battery Fermi levels and the device. This is why ESD is a concern, and there are different tolerances and solution to this.

When you buy an electronic product in the store, or a battery, most of them will have some kind of compatible Fermi level (and tolerance for certain differences) with each other. A new battery to your new controller won't spark to plasma. One of the reasons that they're about on about the same levels initially is because they're of about the same materials, just metals.

Now, assume a simple circuit with just a battery+resistor. The circuits Fermi level will be a gradient-ish (for our purposes) from the high of the battery to the low of the battery. Point is, it's no lower or higher than the levels of the battery.

Now what if I have a very special battery with very high absolute Fermi levels at its poles, but a relative 5V voltage drop. If you connect our simple circuit to it, this circuit will raise to these Fermi levels.

And here's where I have a problem with that:

1) How high (in absolute) can the Fermi level of the battery get in its poles?

2) If these absolute levels on the battery are VERY high (but their difference just 5V or something), and a circuit has to raise to that level as we connect it, how does that effect the circuit (after "equilibrium" has been established)?

3) Same question as (1). How high (in absolute) can the circuit go, when does this matter, does it depend on the material (just solids for now)?

4) I suppose the device gets grounded-ish with the battery?

See where I'm getting at here?

Comment: I don't think that your assumption that the cell voltage is given by the difference in Fermi levels is correct. For a Cu-Zn cell the potential difference is about 1 .1 V whereas the difference between the Fermi levels of the metals is more than double (about 2.5 V). The cells contain metals in a solution so what matters is the electro-chemical potentials. I doubt that you can model all you discuss here in terms of Fermi energy only.

Comment: 2.5V is in room temperature and no source/drain. If Zn and Cu touch each other, they will get into a thermodynamic equilibrium and their Fermi levels equals out. V=(F1-F2)/-e is the voltage you get with a voltage meter. Then, as you say, the chemicals creates an imbalance that changes the levels.

Comment: I thought that by "battery" you really mean battery. I mean, a voltaic cell. Not just two metals in contact.

Comment: Well, I suck at asking questions. 3 threads, all failing at getting understood.